# mysql: Is it possible to view the actual character encoding/collation for individual rows?

Tags: mysql

My understanding of the MySQL character encoding is that you can define default character encoding at the row, column, database and possibly? server level?
I have a situation where different default column and table character encodings, i.e. `utf8_unicode_ci`, `latin` and `utf8_general_ci` have been used at different times that the database has been in production.
So I'm suspecting the actual rows may have different encoding according to the period they were `INSERT`'ed (if its possible to have different rows with different encodings). 
I.e. Im suspecting some rows are `utf8_unicode_ci` some rows are `latin` etc.
Is it possible to view what the **actual** character encoding of the individual rows is?

Im using

- Phpmyadmin Version information: 4.0.10deb1
- Mysql workbench
- mysql command line

Comment: I am fairly certain the encoding cannot vary by row (short of blob data perhaps, but that is outside the scope of the schema design); but I believe encoding can vary by field. To find that information, you could query the `information_schema.columns`.